# MonkeyRunner: A more reliable wait and full length screenshots?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I've been monkeying around with the monkeyrunner - sorry had to try and tell that joke.

I am trying to achieve three things:

1) Only send key hits when my app has fully launched and loaded. How can I do this without relying on the unreliable `MonkeyRunner.sleep(3)`?

2) How can I capture screenshots for the full length of my application (its scrollable), if at all possible?

3) Is it possible to pass parameters to my application via the monkeyrunner so that these parameters can be used within the application?

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Only send key hits when my app has
>   fully launched and loaded. How can I
>   do this without relying on the
>   unreliable MonkeyRunner.sleep(3)?

You would need to use python's subprocess module with adb's logcat to monitor the log and see when your app opened.

> 2) How can I capture screenshots for
>   the full length of my application (its
>   scrollable), if at all possible?

If you are running this on a real device then it is not possible. If you are doing things with an emulator then just make it so the emulator screen is as big as you need the screen shot to be.

> 3) Is it possible to pass parameters
>   to my application via the monkeyrunner
>   so that these parameters can be used
>   within the application?

Yes, see the options that you have [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/MonkeyDevice.html#startActivity).

Comment: Different devices can have different log formats, so this may not be reliable if you'll be using your script with a number of different devices.